# Derivative of f(x)=arth(lnx)

Tags: limits, derivatives, logarithms

I'm struggling with finding derivative of f(x)=arth(lnx).

I've done following:

x=th(y)

f'(x)=(arth(lnx))'=1/(thlnx)'=1/(1/(xch^2(lnx)))=(x(ch^2(lnx)))/(ch^2x-sh^2x)=(ch^2(x(lnx)))/(ch^2(1-th^2x))=(x(lnx))/(1-x^2)

so in conclusion I get f'(arth(lnx))=(x(lnx))/(1-x^2)

but I think it's not correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean $ \tanh^{-1}(\ln x) $ ?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! You need to tidy up your math expressions to help people help you. Check the [help] for information on how to typeset math using MathJax. For example, what is ch? $\cosh$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean $\text{arctanh}{(\ln{x})}$.  In this case, use the fact that

$$\text{arctanh}(z) = \frac12 \ln{\left ( \frac{1+z}{1-z} \right )}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx} \text{arctanh}{(\ln{x})} = \frac12  \left (\frac{1}{1+\ln{x}} + \frac{1}{1-\ln{x}} \right ) \frac{d}{dx} \ln{x} = \frac1{2 x}  \left (\frac{1}{1+\ln{x}} + \frac{1}{1-\ln{x}} \right )$$

Simplifying this a bit, I get

$$\frac{1}{x (1-\ln^2{x})}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $\ \tanh(f(x))=\ln x$, differentiating it we get:
$$\left(1-\tanh^2(f(x)\right)\cdot f'(x) = \frac1x$$
which gives $\ f'(x)=\displaystyle\frac1{x\cdot \left(1-\tanh^2(f(x)\right)} =
\frac1{x\cdot(1-\ln^2(x))}\,$, using $\tanh(f(x))=\ln(x)$.